# TypeError : takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given. Can't figure out what arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a tkinter UI.
I wanna be able to access the Entry at every changes (The User add a character)
So I figured out I should use a callback function like so

```
def callback():
     s = entry.get()
     print (s)
     varStr.trace_variable("w", callback)
```

And i then call that function . But I'm not sure how they work and can't find out.

When I run the program i got this error once I put a character in the Entry field:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I found somewhere I could add 'self' but i still got two more arguments to fill. Could you help me know what they should be ?

Comment: How did you register the callback? Can you show us the line where you use `callback` as a widget command?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I'm guessing it's an indentation problem.  `varStr.trace_variable("w", callback)` looks like it's indented a little too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the exact widget you used `callback()` *for*, it is hard to say exactly what arguments TKInter is trying to pass to it.

You can always give a callback a variable arguments parameter:

```
def callback(*args):
    s = entry.get()
    print (s)
    varStr.trace_variable("w", callback)
```

From [this document](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/ROTKFolklore.html) you can see that a `trace_variable()` callback is passed three arguments:

> - The name of the Tk variable. This is not the Tk variable object itself, but you can use the name to get or set the value via `root.globalgetvar(name)` and `root.globalsetvar(name)`. Unfortunately, I have not found any way to obtain the actual Tk variable object from its name; `root.nametowidget(varName)` does not seem to work for Tk variables.
> - The variable index, if the Tk variable is an array, else an empty string. I have no idea how to create a Tk variable array in Tkinter (but it is easy in Tk). If you figure it out, you can then determine if the index is a string representation of an integer, or an integer (my guess is it's a string).
> - The access mode, one of "w", "r" or "u".

You do *not* need to call `varStr.trace_variable()` each and every time `callback()` is called, however.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this to see which argument it is called with:

```
def callback(*args):
    print ['CALLBACK', args]
    s = entry.get()
    print (s)
    varStr.trace_variable("w", callback)
```

Then consult the documentation of `.trace_variable` or whatever you have registered the callback with for the number of arguments and their meaning.